# How to add "salt" into MD5 encryption in Spring Security 5.x

Tags: spring-security

I have a web application that was built on Spring Security 4.2.17 and uses Md5PasswordEncoder. I plan to upgrade it to Spring Security 5.3.3.RELEASE. I understand that Md5PasswordEncoder is removed from Spring Security 5.x. Let's put aside the strength of the MD5 algorithm. I would like to continue to use it, the exactly same way of how MD5 works in Spring 4.x. Here is how I use Md5PasswordEncoder in the app based on Spring Security 4.2.17:

```
Md5PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encodePassword(plainTextPassword, salt);
```

I understand that in Spring Security 5.x, I can continue use MD5 in this way (I understand it is deprecated)

```
MessageDigestPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("MD5");
```

However, I don't see a way to add the "salt" in encryption because this class (MessageDigestPasswordEncoder) does't seem to use "salt" the same way as in Spring 4.x.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to use `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder` together with a self-generated salt. Instead, [`MessageDigestPasswordEncoder#encode`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.java) itself generates a (random) salt, and returns it together with the hash. However, it is relatively easy to implement the functionality of `org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder` ...

Comment: ...by means of `java.security.MessageDigest` yourself. The crucial methods are [`MessageDigestPasswordEncoder#encodePassword`](https://github.com/DeveloperHuang/Spring-Security-Source-Code/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.java) and [`BasePasswordEncoder#mergePasswordAndSalt`](https://github.com/DeveloperHuang/Spring-Security-Source-Code/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/BasePasswordEncoder.java).

Comment: @Topaco, thanks for your input. My app uses a custom salt (instead of a random one as in Spring Security 5.x), which is a field in a database record for an account. Each account has a its own salt.